# ¿Por qué no se pone la imagen si está en el mismo directorio? Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, imagen

Estuve tratando de poner imágenes en mi ventana, pero no sé porque no puedo. Tengo la imagen en la misma carpeta que el código y aun así me sale un error , como que no se pudo reconocer. Me cuesta un poco explicarlo, pero creo que con mi código se podrá entender un poco más.

Este es mi código:

```
from tkinter import *
ventana = Tk()
ventana.geometry("700x650")
ventana.title("example of images")

imagen = PhotoImage(file= "australia.png" )
Label(ventana, image= imagen)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Este es el error que obtengo:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/josef/Desktop/curso python/imagen.py", line 6, in <module>
    imagen=PhotoImage(file= "australia.png" )
  File "C:\Users\josef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4061, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\josef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4006, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "australia.png"
PS C:\Users\josef\Desktop\curso python>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tkinter en si no soporta formatos de imágenes (los más comunes), soporta archivos .ppm. Estos generados a través de objetos que se crean con la clase `ImageTk`, disponible en la librería [PIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library) (*Python Imaging Library*).

Para el caso de Tkinter se ocupa generar un objeto tipo `Image` y a base de este generar otro tipo `PhotoImage`, por medio del modulo `ImageTk`:

```
imagen = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("australia.png"))
```

Como cualquier imagen que se abre con PIL, se usa `Image.open()`. La diferencia aquí es que ese objeto luego sirve para inicializar un objeto de tipo `PhotoImage`, que es específico para Tkinter. Ahora veamos un ejemplo práctico:

```
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
imagen = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("australia.png"))
fondo = tk.Label(root,image = imagen)
fondo.pack() #Se ubica la imagen de fundo
root.mainloop()
```

La imagen `australia.png` la saqué de Google, funciona igual con la que ya tengas. En este caso usé `pack()` para la ubicación del elemento, pero también se puede usar `place()` o hasta `grid()` (este último no lo recomiendo). El código resulta en esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te haya servido de algo.

Comment: muchas gracias te pasaste, todo comprendido, agradezco que te hayas tomado el tiempo para responderme, pude entender todo a la perfeccion, ahora solo me toca aplicarlo. saludos