# ¿Cómo solucionar el error en vs code al usar tkinter "couldn't open "file.png": no such file or directory "?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, vscode

Estoy usando Visual Studio Code con Python 3, y me encuentro viendo la librería `Tkinter` para hacer una GUI. El programa es una interfaz en la cual sale una imagen de un avión y abajo salen 3 `check buttons` uno sobre otro. El código resumido es el siguiente:

```
from tkinter import *

ventana = Tk()
ventana.title("Ejemplo")
   
foto = PhotoImage(file="avion.png")
Label(ventana, image = foto).pack()
```

La situación es que cuando ejecuto el código desde Visual Studio Code, en el modo *"Ejecutar archivo Python en la terminal"* me sale el error:

> "_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "avion.png": no such file or directory"

Sin embargo, este error no aparece cuando ejecuto el mismo programa en CMD o PowerShell de Windows.

Si alguien me pudiese ayudar sería muy bueno, gracias.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué no se pone la imagen si está en el mismo directorio? Tkinter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/374061/por-qu%c3%a9-no-se-pone-la-imagen-si-est%c3%a1-en-el-mismo-directorio-tkinter)

Comment: @Gabitohh Lamentablemente no, ya que la imagen si se incluye en el programa cuando se ejecuta desde el cmd o sublime text por ejemplo, sin embargo unicamente en visual studio code no funciona, muchas gracias de todas manera.

Comment: @Gabitohh. El duplicado que propones es un problema con el formato de imagen; la pregunta de Petra es por un archivo no encontrado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El directorio de trabajo del terminal de *Visual Studio Code* es diferente del directorio que contiene al archivo *avion.png*. Fíjate en que el terminal ejecuta tu *script* utilizando su **path absoluto**.

`foto = PhotoImage(file="avion.png")` solamente funcionará si `os.getcwd()` es el mismo directorio de la imágen, lo que no se cumple cuando ejecutas con *visual studio code*.

**Puedes asegurar que tu *script* encuentre los recursos que necesita independientemente del directorio de trabajo del *shell* que ejecuta a *python*.**

Si *avion.png* está en la misma carpeta que el *script* que lo requiere puedes obtener el **path absoluto de la imágen** así:

```
import os

absolute_folder_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

absolute_image_path = os.path.join(absolute_folder_path, 'avion.png')
```

Utiliza `absolute_image_path` para cargar la imagen:

```
foto = PhotoImage(file=absolute_image_path)
```

Esto funcionará independientemente de cómo y donde ejecutes el *script*.

También podrías trabajar con `sys.argv[0]` (que es el *path del script* que se ejecuta) para obtener el *path de la imágen*. Por ejemplo:

```
import sys, os

script_path = sys.argv[0]

folder, script = os.path.split(script_path)

image_path = os.path.join(folder, 'avion.png')
```

En este caso no estás utilizando el *path absoluto de la imágen* sino el **path relativo correcto en relación al directorio de trabajo**.

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias @tecnobillo. Sabes si hay alguna diferencia entre hacer lo que tú dijiste y anotar toda la ruta directamente de esta manera: C:/Users/pe/Desktop/Practica/intentos/avion.png

Comment: La única diferencia es que si mueves el programa a otra carpeta tendrás que modificar la ruta en el *script*, pero si obtienes la ruta *dinámicamente* no tienes que preocuparte por modificar el código (así tu programa es mas *portable*, no depende de en que carpeta esté). Un saludo! :)

Comment: muchas gracias !

Comment: No hay de que! para eso estamos, yo también aprendo mucho leyendo por aquí ^^